# Tool to generate change reports from Subversion logs

Tags: svn

Is there a good tool to generate change reports from Subversion logs.

We have big team and many commits every day. I'm looking for some tool to show changes in all files. We are using Subversion, so I'm looking some tool that can read Subversion logs.

Answer (score 16):

svn2cl generates nice html pages from an svn log
http://ch.tudelft.nl/~arthur/svn2cl/

To create a html page instead of the default text output, run

```
svn log --xml -v > log.xml
xsltproc.exe --nowrite --nomkdir --nonet -o changelog.html svn2html.xsl log.xml
```

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to svnmonitor would be the [CommitMonitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html).

Comment: @Stefan - does it checks for one user or for all users?

Answer (score 4):

I use [SVNStat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnstat) to generate these kind of reports nightly.

Answer (score 3):

one word: trac.
trac.edgewall.org

Comment: we use this at work too, it is an amazing tool, if only for tracking changes made.  But there is so much more to it